# Libre Office, Clearing a Range

Tags: vba, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have been looking online to get the idea how to acess a range and then "clearing" it. Sadly even though i have found several solutions, vba in libre office makes things really complicated to understand. I have tried to record a macro, and edit it... It works but not as i want it to. I need to execute the below code from a Form (Dialog) and it does what its meant to, but shows everything in the background and I can't have that .... is there a way, to do this ? for example in vba Exel I would just write :

```
Range("A1:DA25000").ClearContents (or .Delete)
```

Here is what I got with macro recordings:

```
Function Brisanje()

dim document   as object
dim dispatcher as object

document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

dim args1(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args1(0).Name = "Nr"
args1(0).Value = 2

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:JumpToTable", "", 0, args1())

dim args2(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args2(0).Name = "ToPoint"
args2(0).Value = "$A$1:$DA$25000"

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:GoToCell", "", 0, args2())

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:ClearContents", "", 0, Array())

end Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are looking for is in [Andrew Pitonyak's macro document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php), section `6.4. Clear a cell`.  Notice that the code works for multiple cells as well:

> REM You can use a range such as "A1:B2"

Macro recordings are not a good way to learn how to write macros.  They generate dispatcher code, which is different from working with the UNO API.